# Notification on Stack Overflow is shown even after viewing it

Tags: bug, notifications

1. I got 10+ which is shown in notification.
2. I saw it's details, then the 10+ notification should not be visible.
3. I refreshed the page , then again th 10+ notification was visible.

[image]
[image]Repro Steps:

Comment: Maybe [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268957/topbar-notifications-dont-go-away) is back!

Comment: And you sure it's for the same vote? Maybe you got two upvotes in a row. Also the user who voted might have undo the vote then voted again, resulting in the 10 to appear again.

Comment: I have encountered the same bug, though I also do not know how to reproduce it.

Comment: I am 100% sure it is for the same vote up..